# Deleting and Renaming in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using an html form with a JS upload field to update the site logo.

I am trying to:

1. Upload the new logo using the form
2. Delete the old logo to free up the name
3. Rename the uploaded logo so it is rendered as per the HTML (Light_Logo_Nav)

So far I have the following but it is not working:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['Edit_Business_Details'] ) && '1' === $_POST['Edit_Business_Details']){
    $URLcheck='https';
    $New_Light_Logo_Nav = $_POST['light_logo_nav'];
    $Light_Logo_Nav_Directory_Name = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/Light_Logo_Nav";

        { 
            if(strpos($New_Light_Logo_Nav, $URLcheck) !== false){
                unlink($Light_Logo_Nav_Directory_Name);
                rename($New_Light_Logo_Nav , $Light_Logo_Nav_Directory_Name);
         }}}
```

Upon form submission, the file will have already been uploaded to the base directory and $_POST['light_logo_nav'] will contain the file path in the format:
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/Light_Logo_Nav.png

Comment: "but it is not working".... (?)

Comment: Yes, I think there is something wrong with manipulating the file paths?

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Please read it, and adapt your question with all the information needed. Currently there is a variable `ABDPATH` which is not defined in the piece of code shown. Also it is unclear what "is not working", of why "there is something wrong with the file paths"

Comment: I'm not sure how to improve on that? It is quite straightforward but perhaps the name has it wrong? The solution should be quite simple and straight ( I will answer it myself later once I get it working).

Please don't assume everyone is a pro, bear there are students (myself). 

I don't know what you mean by defining the ABSPATH but should be a route to the solution and I said "I think" hence I am not sure if that is why.

 I'd also advice you to keep this site professional, if you think there is something wrong in my post it would be nice to learn constructively and not sarcastically.

Comment: So have you tried to debug and narrow down what path is being used? And have you got error reporting enabled in the PHP config?

Comment: Easy guys, Ali Hamdan - 'is not working' is too less - what error? next time quote any errors, then coders won't eat you alive; please, remove this useless `{` between conditions, quick debugging guide - right after each condition or declaration put `echo "OK $variable";` or something - let php to talk to you; Leave ABDPATH alone, its not a variable; `===` replace with `==` and run

Comment: I see that is something from wordpress, here a post from 6 years ago: [ABSPATH](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134594/absolute-path-abspath-in-wordpress-is-not-working). Yuo should check if it has the correct (expected) value.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they pointed me in the right direction. I have posted the answer to how I got deletion to work.

Comment: Thanks @Luuk for your comments

Comment: Thanks @ADyson for your comments

Comment: Thanks @blackblue for your comments and suggestion, I should learn how to talk to PHP. I don't know why I need to do that yet, but sounds sensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all who commented, you comments pointed me in the right direction.

The problem was that the format https://example.. was not accepted for deleting, I was receiving the error **unlink(): http does not allow unlinking**

The work around I created was to save the name in a custom field, then use the ABSPATH, the following script shows how I filtered the URL to get the file name, then plug it into the ABSPATH

```
if ( isset( $_POST['Edit_Business_Details'] ) && '1' == $_POST['Edit_Business_Details']){
    $URLcheck='https';
    $New_Light_Logo_Nav = $_POST['light_logo_nav'];
    $light_logo_nav= get_post_meta( 10416, 'light_logo_nav' );
    $light_logo_nav_del=$light_logo_nav[0];
    $disallowed = array('http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/', 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/');
    $Updated_Light_Logo_Nav = array
    
        (
                                'light_logo_nav'    => $New_Light_Logo_Nav,
        );

    if(strpos($New_Light_Logo_Nav, $URLcheck) !== false){
        foreach($disallowed as $d) {
            if(strpos($light_logo_nav_del, $d) === 0) {
                $delete_existing_light_logo_nav=str_replace($d, '', $light_logo_nav_del);
                    wp_delete_file(ABSPATH . '/wp-content/uploads/'.$delete_existing_light_logo_nav);
      }
   }
                    wp_update_post(array(
                                           'ID'        => 10416,
                                           'meta_input'=> $Updated_Light_Logo_Nav));
}
}
```

This was working I don't need to rename since I am dynamically requesting the custom field in HTML.